# IndentationError: unexpected indent - python script

Tags: python, linux, gmail-api

I have issue when executing my python script on my linux server, can someone know what is wrong with my script?

```
def construct_service(api_service):
    CLIENT_SERVICE_FILE = "mygcpkey.json"
    try:
        if api_service == 'drive':
            API_NAME = 'drive'
            API_VERSION = 'v3'
            SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
            return Create_Service(CLIENT_SERVICE_FILE, API_NAME, API_VERSION, SCOPES)
         elif api_service == 'gmail':
         API_NAME = 'gmail'
         API_VERSION = 'v1'
         SCOPES = ['https://mail.google.com/']
         return Create_Service(CLIENT_SERVICE_FILE, API_NAME, API_VERSION, SCOPES)
```

Error

```
  File "bgmail.py", line 14
    elif api_service == 'gmail':
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Comment: `elif` must line up with the `if`.  `if` is 8 spaces, and `elif` is 9.  And then the code to run in the `elif` must be indented.

Comment: The elif is one space too far. and then the next line should be indented.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without having the "exact" code. In copy-paste you might have changed a tab to 4 spaces or vice versa and the rest of the code has the other. That's what I typically have when I've copied something from the web and they use a different whitespace setup than I (I know that PEP8 suggests 4 spaces of indentation, but I prefer tab that render as 2 spaces in VSCode, for example). That is something that you might have ran into.

And actually, this should look like this

```py
         elif api_service == 'gmail':
             #Here you also need to indent...
             API_NAME = 'gmail'
             API_VERSION = 'v1'
             SCOPES = ['https://mail.google.com/']
             return Create_Service(CLIENT_SERVICE_FILE, API_NAME, API_VERSION, SCOPES)
```

Comment: I think this is the exact code. In this case you can just count spaces. There is one too many before the `elif`.

Comment: In that case, you have found it! Also, note that after the elif, I've added the identation as well (see my code above). In your code the block after the elif is at the same level as the elif. This won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work:

```
def construct_service(api_service):
    CLIENT_SERVICE_FILE = "mygcpkey.json"
    try:
        if api_service == 'drive':
            API_NAME = 'drive'
            API_VERSION = 'v3'
            SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
            return Create_Service(CLIENT_SERVICE_FILE, API_NAME, API_VERSION, SCOPES)
         elif api_service == 'gmail':
             API_NAME = 'gmail'
             API_VERSION = 'v1'
             SCOPES = ['https://mail.google.com/']
             return Create_Service(CLIENT_SERVICE_FILE, API_NAME, API_VERSION, SCOPES)
```

Comment: I modify my code using your solution I think it work, since the error change to another line it says "IndentationError: unexpected unindent"

Answer (score 0):

If you have PyCharm editor then you can select your code and use code->Reformat code option. Code in your file will be arranged according to code standards.